# AWS Cognito User Pool AdminCreateUser in lambda returns no error nor data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I created an AWS Lambda function to test new Cognito User Pool account creation but no account was created in user pool and no error shown in console log.  I checked AWS Cloud Watch but no error was reported in cloud watch also.

```
START RequestId: ..... Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: .....
REPORT RequestId: .....  Duration: 80.12 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 84 MB
```

I changed my Lambda function to something simpler; describeUserPool.  Still no error was thrown and no user pool info was printed in console.  I added a console.log print within the describeUserPool callback function but that did not print.

The lambda function was created using AWS Console Lambda inline editor.  Lambda function has AmazonESCognitoAccess policy attached (this policy has List/Read/Write access level to Cognito User Pools).

Can anyone shed some lights on what I've gotten wrong?
Thank you very much in advance.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'access_key_id', 
    secretAccessKey: 'secret_access_key',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    apiVersion: '2016-04-18'
});
var cognito = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
var params = {
    UserPoolId: 'us-region-user-pool-id'
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    cognito.describeUserPool(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log('hello from inside function');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
     });
};
```

If I included an incorrect params in AdminCreateUser it reported error

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
    aws.config.update({
        accessKeyId: 'access_key_id', 
        secretAccessKey: 'secret_access_key',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        apiVersion: '2016-04-18'
    });


var cognito = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
var params = {
    UserPoolId: 'us-region-user-pool-id'
    Username: 'someone',
    TemporaryPassword: '11223344',
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: 'EMAIL',
    MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
    UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: 'Email',
      Value: 'someone@example.com'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Family_Name',
        Value: 'One'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Given_Name',
        Value: 'Some'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Phone_Number_verified',
        Value: 'True'
    },
        {
        Name: 'Email_verified',
        Value: 'True'
    }

  ],
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    cognito.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log('hello from inside function');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
     });
};
```

I received the following error message in Lambda inline editor console:

```
Response:
null

Request ID:
"6e50fdb4-e437-4b84-be7b-3caaeb5b0a98"

Function Logs:
    ncCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:391:24)
        at Config.getCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:411:9) {
      code: 'MultipleValidationErrors',
      errors: [
        InvalidParameterType: Expected params.DesiredDeliveryMediums to be an Array
            at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
            at ParamValidator.validateType (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:232:10)
            at ParamValidator.validateList (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:99:14)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:90:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
            at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
            at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:126:42)
            at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
            at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12) {
          code: 'InvalidParameterType',
          time: 2020-05-31T21:59:35.116Z
        },
        InvalidParameterType: Expected params.UserAttributes[3].Value to be a string
            at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
            at ParamValidator.validateType (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:232:10)
            at ParamValidator.validateString (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:154:32)
            at ParamValidator.validateScalar (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:130:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:94:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateList (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:103:14)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:90:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14) {
          code: 'InvalidParameterType',
          time: 2020-05-31T21:59:35.116Z
        },
        InvalidParameterType: Expected params.UserAttributes[4].Value to be a string
            at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
            at ParamValidator.validateType (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:232:10)
            at ParamValidator.validateString (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:154:32)
            at ParamValidator.validateScalar (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:130:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:94:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateList (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:103:14)
            at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:90:21)
            at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14) {
          code: 'InvalidParameterType',
          time: 2020-05-31T21:59:35.116Z
        }
      ],
      time: 2020-05-31T21:59:35.173Z
    }
    END RequestId: 6e50fdb4-e437-4b84-be7b-3caaeb5b0a98
    REPORT RequestId: 6e50fdb4-e437-4b84-be7b-3caaeb5b0a98  Duration: 122.82 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 80 MB  Init Duration: 356.12 ms
```

Comment: Hi, can you see if it was invoked. Check CloudWatch metric

Comment: Triggered "Test" in Lambda console and Cloud Watch confirmed that it ran `successfully.  
Timestamp
Message
There are older events to load. 
Load more.

2020-05-31T16:59:07.766-04:00
START RequestId: 1ea1741e-d9e7-4991-af9d-f72bf73b1133 Version: $LATEST

2020-05-31T16:59:08.202-04:00
END RequestId: 1ea1741e-d9e7-4991-af9d-f72bf73b1133

2020-05-31T16:59:08.202-04:00
REPORT RequestId: 1ea1741e-d9e7-4991-af9d-f72bf73b1133 Duration: 434.49 ms Billed Duration: 500 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 83 MB Init Duration: 337.21 ms`.  However there's no CloudWatch metric for Cognito.

Comment: I changed the function call back to AdminCreateUser.  That did not produce any CloudWatch log.  Looks like lambda is not triggering CognitoIdentifyServiceProvider function call at all.

Answer (score 2):

Found this post [cognito admin not giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046662/aws-cognito-adminupdateuserattributes-not-working-and-not-giving-an-error-am).  Suggestion by @thopaw solved the issue that I was having.

By changing it to promise() base it works as expected.
Thank you guys for your time.

In case anyone came across this, below is the updated code.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('starts');
    var data;
    try {
        const data = await cognito.adminCreateUser(params).promise();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing, I could not find this in the docs -_-