# Lambda, updating Cognito custom user attributes doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

iv been setting up a lambda instance, it grabs data from a few different services and then its meant to update a custom Cognito attribute for that user, that works correctly and i get the return response "{}" along and no errors so im assuming that means its working correctly, however when i check the users attributes its not returning anything?

i have triple checked that the app clients have read and write permissions, so i have no idea whats happening, everything, as far as i can tell, is working, just that the attribute isnt changing.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

console.log("TestInside");
// setTimeout(function() {
console.log("TimeoutFunction");

var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
var params = {
UserAttributes: [
{
Name: 'locale',
Value: UserFarms
},

],
UserPoolId: 'UserPoolID',
Username: UserName
};
console.log("Executing call");
const cognitoD = cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, function(err, data) {

if (err) {
console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
//passon = err.message;
resolve('Error');
}
else {
// cognitodata = data;
console.log('Returned positive cognito admin update');
//UserName = data.Username;
//passon = data;
console.log(data);
resolve(data);
}
}).promise();
```

whats wrong, am i missing somthing really simple?

Comment: I would consider using await/async, that would make mistakes easier to spot.

Comment: i'm already calling this inside a function that's being called from another async function so i didn't have that option unless i made this function also async... in saying that, iv tested this exact piece of code inside a async function with await and im still having the same problem. returning successfully but not changing anything? is there perhaps a setting i'm missing?

Comment: I agree with @Robert Koss above, try to await adminUpdateUserAttributes and remove that promise
`try{
    // no callback here
    const data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider
      .adminUpdateUserAttributes(attributes)
      .promise()
    console.log('success', data)
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('error', error)
  }
)}`

Comment: this problem looks similar to yours (I found it after posting the previous) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046662/aws-cognito-adminupdateuserattributes-not-working-and-not-giving-an-error-am

Comment: unfortunately, that hasn't worked, iv changed the code again, using the code you wrote @stamstam, and also tried with the code from the other post, and i'm getting "success {}", but still nothing is changing?. its the same problem (or lack thereof) the function is executing just fine, but its not doing anything?

Comment: I don't know why you need the .promise(), but in case you do, have you tried put cognitoD in a try-catch, like this 
`try{
let cognitoD = cognitoidentityserviceprovider......etc(all the code you have)
context.succeed();
} catch (err){
        context.fail(err);
}`

Comment: i didn't have the promise in that last test, i just created a new function and basically just copy and pasted your code, but its not changing any of the client attributes, and returning no errors, just success?